# How to remove Account section from Footer?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, footer, page

I wanna remove the Account section from Footer menu.

[image]

I have created local.xml with the code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <remove name="footer_links2"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But still the Account section is there.

Answer (score 2):

For information `<remove />` is a node which doesn't **need** to be inside any other node or reference.

1) Create well your `local.xml` in your current them like this:

`app/design/frontend/{currentPackage}/{currentTheme}/layout/local.xml`

2) add this code inside like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <remove name="footer_links2"/>
    </default>
</layout>
```

3) Clear Magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml

Line number : 143 to 145

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
</block>
```

Comment above code block or remove the code that will be remove account links from footer.

Answer (score 0):

My local.xml codes are okay... It just worked after cleared the cache.

Comment: Please accept one answer